# free_result and codeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I've tried this  as a codeIgniter function code but I do Not know why it doesn't work.

```
 $o = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `w` WHERE id = '2'"); 

    foreach ($o->result() as $row)
    {
        echo $row->lasthit;
    }       
    $o->free_result();
```

so when I try to 'echo $row->lasthit' again, I see the same result!

Comment: have you initialized the database class before this query ?? `$this->load->database();`

Answer (score 1):

Check first the autoload, is the database autoloaded? If not, you have to do it manually, the best place for this is in the model constructor. Or if you need on every page the database, then autoload it.